# Create round corner video object

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I want to create a rounded corner video object to my video player. This is how I create my object:

```
var videoCamera:Video = new Video(300, 225);
```

The problem is that it will make the object square video. But i want the corner of the object to be round instead of square. I have searched a lot on google and could not find any example or fix to this problem.

I also did this, but it dont work..

```
videoCamera.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00ff00, 1); //Last arg is the alpha
videoCamera.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1); //Last arg is the alpha
videoCamera.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 25, 25)
videoCamera.graphics.endFill();
addChild( videoCamera);
```

Please help me to make the video object have rounded corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you are looking for, you can simply use a [`mask`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0b.html), like this :

```
var video:Video = new Video(320, 180);
    video.x = video.y = 50;
addChild(video);

var rounded:Shape = new Shape();
    rounded.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
    rounded.graphics.drawRoundRect(video.x, video.y, video.width, video.height, 25, 25);
    rounded.graphics.endFill();
addChild(rounded);

video.mask = rounded;
```

That's all !

Hope that can help.

Comment: that almost help, but how can video.y get moved : 10 px down without video.x also move

Comment: @sarahansen What do you mean ? `video.x = video.y = 50;` can be written `video.x = 50; video.y = 50;` !

Comment: Perfect and sorry akmozo that i can't vote you 1000+, but a kiss :* you can have